# make the compiler not to automatically flush the buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Why does the below code **not** stop the compiler from flushing the buffer automatically?

```
cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(nullptr);
cout << "hello";
cout << "world";
int a;
cin >> a;
```

output:

```
helloworld
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Comment: [Relevant comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n#comment6217683_214076)

Comment: The stream can flush out the character whenever it feels like doing so.

Comment: @DanielKO But in any reasonable implementation, it won't.  It will only flush when requested, or when the buffer is full.  And I can't imagine his text filling the buffer.  (On the other hand, by default, when you input from `std::cin`, it will flush `std::cout`.)

Comment: @James Kanze Why? If I spent some good amount of time optimizing fprintf, I might as well use its internal buffering instead of having another buffer on top. Why would that be unreasonable?

Comment: @DanielKO Why would `std::ostream` have anything to do with `fprintf`?  That would just slow it down, by adding yet another layer of indirection.

Comment: @James Kanze cout can be of any concrete type, as long as it inherits from std::ostream. It can do whatever it wants, even print through fprintf(), which is a great tool for the job. For example, libstdc++ implements cout using __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf. Not using fprintf, but fwrite. Same thing.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I recall stepping into MSVC's ostream<<int and it uses some `printf` call or another under the hood IIRC.

Comment: @DanielKO Of course.  An implementation could also sleep for 5 seconds for each character output, and still be conform.  There's also QoI considerations.  One has certain expectations, at least on certain systems; systems should meet them, from a quality point of view.  And most systems do fail in one way or another, on specific points.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure what you are arguing... a good implementation should use straight syscalls to avoid using stdio functions? MS and libstdcxx (used by clang) do it this way too.

Comment: @DanielKO A good implementation will either use system calls directly (if it isn't trying to be portable), or will use `fwrite` or something similar, which still leaves the buffering up to `std::ostream`.  If you're familiar with the interface to `std::streambuf`, this is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the stream can be flushed whenever the implementation likes to do so, i.e. there's no guarantee that the stream will be flushed after an insert operation. However, you could use one of these manipulators to ensure your stream gets flushed (these are the only ones I know of so if someone is aware of others, please comment):

- [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) - inserts a newline into the stream and flushes it,
- [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) - just flushes the stream,
- [`std::(no)unitbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf) - enables/disables flushing the stream after each insert operation.

Comment: Essentially, you can only force it to flush; you can't force it to not flush.

Comment: By saying <code>stream</code>, are you talking about the <code>cin</code>'s stream or every possible IO stream in the standard library, such as in-memory string IO?

Comment: @atoi.powered In an in-memory string IO, flush could easily be a no-op.  But the standard does allow an implementation to call it whenever it wants.

Answer (score 1):

The standard allows an implementation to flush any time it feels
like it, but from a quality of implementation point of view, one
really doesn't expect a flush here.  You might try adding
a `setbuf`, telling `std::cin` to use a buffer you specify:

```
std::cout.rdbuf()->setbuf( buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
```

Again,the standard doesn't guarantee anything, but if this isn't
respected, I'd consider the quality bad enough to warrant a bug
report.

Finally, if worse comes to worse, you can always insert
a filtering streambuf which does the buffering you want.  You
shouldn't have to, but it won't be the first time we've had to
write extra code to work around a lack of quality in compilers
or libraries.  If all you're doing is straightforward output (no
seeks, or anything, something like the following should do the
trick:

```
class BufferingOutStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    std::ostream* myOwner;
    std::vector<char> myBuffer;

    static size_t const bufferSize = 1000;
protected:
    virtual int underflow( int ch )
    {
        return sync() == -1 
            ? EOF
            : sputc( ch );
    }
    virtual int sync()
    {
        int results = 0;
        if ( pptr() != pbase() ) {
            if ( myDest->sputn( pbase(), pptr() - pbase() )
                    != pptr() - pbase() ) {
                results = -1;
            }
        }
        setp( &myBuffer[0], &myBuffer[0] + myBuffer.size() );
        return results;
    }
public:
    BufferingOutStreambuf( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myOwner( NULL )
        , myBuffer( bufferSize )
    {
        setp( &myBuffer[0], &myBuffer[0] + myBuffer.size() );
    }

    BufferingOutStreambuf( std::ostream& dest )
        : myDest( dest.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &dest )
        , myBuffer( bufferSize )
    {
        setp( &myBuffer[0], &myBuffer[0] + myBuffer.size() );
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }

    ~BufferingOutStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != NULL ) {
            myOwner->rdbuf( myDest );
        }
    }
};
```

Then just do:

```
BufferingOutStreambuf buffer( std::cout );
```

as the first line in `main`.  (One could argue that iostreams
should have been designed to work like this from the start, with
filtering streambuf for buffering *and* code translation.  But
it wasn't, and this *shouldn't* be necessary with a decent
implementation.)